# what's a representative mapping of a rotation around the $z-$axis?

Tags: calculus, geometry

let $C =\{ (1+\frac12 \cos \phi,0,\frac12 \sin \phi) \; | \; \phi \in \mathbb{R}\}$

in some old lecture notes of geometry it is stated that :

$f(\mathbb{R^2}) = \bigcup_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}} R_{\theta}(C)$

where $f : \mathbb{\mathbb{R^2 \to R^3}}$ is defined by $f(\theta,\phi) = (\cos \theta(1+\frac12\cos \phi),\sin \theta(1+\frac12\cos \phi),\frac12 \sin \phi)$

and $R_{\theta}$ is the rotation of angle $\theta$ around  the $z-$axis.

I'm a bit lost here, as I don't know how to explicitly  write down a formula for $R_{\theta}$.

can someone clarify this ?

Comment: Judging from the title question I would have answered $(x,y,z)\mapsto (x\cos(\theta)+y\sin(\theta), -x\sin(\theta)+y\cos(\theta), z)$, but when I read the body of your question I have no idea what you are talking about.  So I guess some clarification is needed as to what you are looking for.

Comment: @rschwieb that's it. that's all I needed. thanks.

Comment: For what it is worth - $C$ is a circle of radius $1/2$ in the plane $y = 0$ centered around the point $(1, 0, 0)$. $\bigcup_{\theta \in \mathbb{R}} R_{\theta}(C)$ is the rotation of that circle around the $z$ axis. I.e. a torus of major radius $1$ and minor radius $1/2$. $f$ is the canonical mapping from $\S^1 \times S^1$ onto the torus (combined of course with the canonical mapping $\Bbb R \to S^1$ in each coordinate).